# How to embed JSTL forEach in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to loop through a list of objects (some measurements data) using JSTL forEach tag in javascript and display the data by using Google Charts API. The code is showing as following. But looks something wrong. As I double checked, the data in the list of measurements objects works fine to pass to html in `${listOfMeasurements}`, `${measurements.measTime}`, `${measurements.measS1raw}` and `${measurements.measS2raw}`. But in the javascript block, the forEach code is not working to execute `data.addRow()` as expected. My guess is, I'm not using forEach correctly in my javascript code, so `data.addRow()` was not executed as expected. How can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'measurement1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'measurement2');
     <c:forEach items="${listOfMeasurements}" var="measurements">
        "data.addRow("
        +"${measurements.measTime}"+","
        +"${measurements.measS1raw}"+","
        +"${measurements.measS2raw}"+");"
        ;
     </c:forEach>

    var options = {
      title: 'Measurements'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Try it without the quotes inside the for. In the `forEach` eyes `data.addRow(...)` its already just some string.

Comment: You need to realise that JSP is a HTML code generator and that JS is part of HTML. Open JSP page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Look closer at the JSP-generated HTML/JS code syntax. Is it all right? If not, just fix the JSP code accordingly so that it generates exactly the desired HTML/JS code output. If still in vain, copypaste that HTML output instead of the JSP source code and reframe the question in HTML context instead of JSP context.

Comment: Check HTML source is very helpful. @BalusC, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfMeasurements}" var="measurements">
   data.addRow(${measurements.measTime},${measurements.measS1raw},${measurements.measS2raw});
</c:forEach>
```

Otherwise you will obtain wrong code in your script, for example:

```
"data.addRow("+"measTimeValue-1"+","+"measS1raw-1"+","+"measS2raw-1"");";
"data.addRow("+"measTimeValue-2"+","+"measS1raw-2"+","+"measS2raw-2"");";
"data.addRow("+"measTimeValue-3"+","+"measS1raw-3"+","+"measS2raw-3"");";
```

...and that's incorrect javascript.

The problem with mixing JSP tags and Javascript is that they occur in two differents phases.
JSP Rendering comes first, so all html, css and javascript code is just **another string**. So after the JSP Rendering finishes, you have just HTML.

You may want to read [this blog entry](http://balusc.blogspot.com.ar/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) from [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) about this topic.

Comment: Sorry, posted without wanting to. Edited.

Comment: <c:forEach items="${listOfMeasurements}" var="measurements">
   data.addRow('${measurements.measTime}',${measurements.measS1raw},${measurements.measS2raw}); It works as show above. My Eclipse IDE complains for syntax errors though, a little weird.
</c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

This could be alternate solution....

```
function drawBasic() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Date', 'measurement1','measurement2']
            <c:forEach var="measurements" items="${listOfMeasurements}">
                ,[${measurements.measTime},${measurements.measS1raw},${measurements.measS2raw}]
            </c:forEach>
        ]);         

      var options = {
        title: 'Change title Acoordingly',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Change title Acoordingly',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Change title Acoordingly'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<body><div id="chart_div"></div></body>
```